# how do i get a list of nearby users in an android application efficiently?

Tags: android, location

I am building an application that gets a list of nearby users. Apps like Grindr or Badoo do exactly what i am trying to achieve in this.

I know i have to upload users current location every few minutes to database. And then when a user wants to look for other nearby users search through all database.

Example:

I have 200 000 online users in my app. User want to find first 20 nearest other users. Every user has his location stored in database. So i calculate distance between user and other users and choose nearest 20.

I do not think this approach is efficient. Is there better solution?

Is it possible to implement this with google Nearby API?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't so much an android problem as a backend server problem. I'd send a lat long to my server every *time iteration variable*. Then it's search for users with a last location sooner than *time you decide a location is bad* and with a lat and long both closer than *arbitrary radius* and do a distance search on the remaining and the server than returns the closest 20.

Comment: and if i would not find nearest 20... i woud scale radius...i will try it

Answer (score 0):

All the load must be on the server, the app should only send the location of the user and on the backend should look for the nearest 'n' users using the distance formula or Google Matrix

If there are many users, consider clustering